# Helm install elk-stack with local Storage - node affinity conflict

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install an elk-stack using helm.

I have a master and 3 nodes. On each host, I defined the folder /mnt/elsatic
and created the necessary pvc-s.

At the start, 2 StatefulSets and some pods do not start due to a sl error.

```
0/4 nodes are available: 1 node (s) had taints that didn’t tolerate, 3 node (s) had volume node affinity conflict.
```

Tell me how you can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `I defined the folder /mnt/elsatic and created the necessary pvc-s` Could you provide the config of your PVC?

Comment: Thank. Already I understood. Finally set NFS-Server